# Why do we need to input both (camera_matrix 1 & 2) and (R and T) params to stereoRectify()?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

To do stereo calibrate we need to do 3 steps (input params --> output params):

1. [`calibrateCamera()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#void%20stereoRectify(InputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20InputArray%20R,%20InputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20R1,%20OutputArray%20R2,%20OutputArray%20P1,%20OutputArray%20P2,%20OutputArray%20Q,%20int%20flags,%20double%20alpha,%20Size%20newImageSize,%20Rect*%20validPixROI1,%20Rect*%20validPixROI2)): obj_corners, img_corners --> camera_matrix, distortion_coeffs
2. [`stereoCalibrate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#double%20stereoCalibrate(InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints1,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints2,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20OutputArray%20R,%20OutputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20E,%20OutputArray%20F,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags)): obj_corners, img_corners1/2, camera_matrix1/2, distortion_coeffs1/2 --> R, T, E, F
3. [`stereoRectify()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#stereorectify): camera_matrix1/2, distortion_coeffs1/2, R, T --> R1/2, P1/2, Q

Some params I missed.

And now we can use Q for [`reprojectImageTo3D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#void%20reprojectImageTo3D(InputArray%20disparity,%20OutputArray%20_3dImage,%20InputArray%20Q,%20bool%20handleMissingValues,%20int%20ddepth)) and P1 or P2 for [`triangulatePoints()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#triangulatepoints).

But why do we need to input both (camera_matrix 1 & 2) and (R & T) params to [`stereoRectify()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#stereorectify)?

As known [camera_matrix](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/camera.html?highlight=cameraparams#detail::CameraParams) already contain R & T:

```
struct CV_EXPORTS CameraParams
{
    CameraParams();
    CameraParams(const CameraParams& other);
    const CameraParams& operator =(const CameraParams& other);
    Mat K() const;

    double focal; // Focal length
    double aspect; // Aspect ratio
    double ppx; // Principal point X
    double ppy; // Principal point Y
    Mat R; // Rotation
    Mat t; // Translation
};
```

What's the difference between R & T which we get from [`calibrateCamera()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#void%20stereoRectify(InputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20InputArray%20R,%20InputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20R1,%20OutputArray%20R2,%20OutputArray%20P1,%20OutputArray%20P2,%20OutputArray%20Q,%20int%20flags,%20double%20alpha,%20Size%20newImageSize,%20Rect*%20validPixROI1,%20Rect*%20validPixROI2)) and R & T that contained in CameraParams which we get from [`stereoCalibrate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=calibratecamera#double%20stereoCalibrate(InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints1,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints2,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix1,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs1,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix2,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs2,%20Size%20imageSize,%20OutputArray%20R,%20OutputArray%20T,%20OutputArray%20E,%20OutputArray%20F,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags))?

Comment: You seem to be mixing the camera matrix (only the intrinsic parameters) and the CameraParams structure of the stitching namespace, which contains other stuff, including the extrinsics.

Comment: @Joan Charmant I.e. camera matrix - 3x3 matrix (only the intrinsic parameters `K`), but `stitch::detail::CameraParams` - 3x4 matrix (the intrinsic and the extrinsics parameters `K * [R|t]`), isn't it? Does it mean, that  `stitch::detail::CameraParams` is a P (projection matrix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is inconsistent terminology. What OpenCV calls *camera matrix* is a 3x3 matrix `K` containing the intrinsics. What Harley and Zisserman call *camera matrix* is a 3x4 camera projection matrix `P = K * [R|t]`, which includes both the intrinsics and the extrinsics.

Comment: Thank you. But is `stitch::detail::CameraParams` a projection matrix `P = K * [R|t]`? Because it contains `R` & `T` and `K`:  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/camera.html  Where `K` is: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ddf82d0b154873510802ef75c53e628cd7b2cb13/modules/stitching/src/camera.cpp#L64

Comment: `stitch::detail::CameraParams` is a C++ class, not a matrix. The `stereoRectify()` function does not take a `CameraParams` object. It takes `cv::Mat` objects containing the matrices.

Comment: Yes, I mean that `stitch::detail::CameraParams` contain all the same data as the `P`, and we can get `P` from the `stitch::detail::CameraParams`.