# How can I get P (projection matrix) from only two CameraParams, if images already undistorted?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

To get **P** for 1st/2nd cameras (Output 3x4 projection matrix in the new (rectified) coordinate systems for the first camera) we can use this approach: `calibrateCamera()` --> `stereoCalibrate()` --> `stereoRectify()`, as there: [Why do we need to input both (camera_matrix 1 & 2) and (R and T) params to stereoRectify()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593847/why-do-we-need-to-input-both-camera-matrix-1-2-and-r-and-t-params-to-stere)

But if I have not: obj_corners, img_corners, distortion_coeffs, R, T. But I already have 2 undistorted images and two CameraParams [`struct stitch::detail::CameraParams`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/camera.html?highlight=cameraparams#detail::CameraParams) which I get from [`stitch::detail::Estimator`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/motion_estimation.html?highlight=homographybasedestimator#detail::HomographyBasedEstimator%20:%20public%20detail::Estimator) for each of 2 images, then can I get **P** (3x4 projection matrix) and how can I do it?

How can I get P (projection matrix) from only two `stitch::detail::CameraParams` without any addition params, if images already undistorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `P` is `P = K * [R|t]`, where `K` is the intrinsics matrix.

Comment: I.e. I need to do: `Mat RT  = Mat(3, 4, CV_64F);` `R.copyTo(RT(Rect(0,0,3,3)));` `T.copyTo(RT(Rect(3,0,1,3)));` `stitch::detail::CameraParams CP;` `Mat P = CP.K() * RT;` - we get P [cols=3, rows=4] is it right?

Comment: Yes, assuming that `CP` contains valid camera parameters.